# MySQL Data Reader and Checkbox

Tags: c#, mysql, combobox, reader

I want to read NULL values from database, if its not NULL I want to make the checkboxes checked but this code is not working.

```
if (dr["p51"] != null)
{
chkP51.Checked = true;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the values null by using [DataRow.IsNull(string columnName)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3fwatee0(v=vs.110).aspx).
Change your code like this.

```
if (!dr.IsNull("p51"))
{
    chkP51.Checked = true;
}
```

Finally from @Kevin Rodriguez suggestion,because `dr["p51"]` return 0

```
if ((string)dr["p51"] == "0")
{
    chkP51.Checked = true;
}
```

Comment: there is no IsNull property only dr.IsDBNull

Comment: What about dr.DBNull("p51") ?

Comment: Sorry try this dr.IsDBNull("p51") and check your column Name

Comment: sorry my mistake, the values is not null, it has 0 if no value, how can check if the values is equal to 0?

Comment: try this if (dr["p51"] == 0)

Comment: im getting Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'int'

Comment: if ((Integer) dr["p51"] == 0) check this or if ((int) dr["p51"] == 0).

Comment: im getting invalid specified cast

Comment: solved, thanks i used (string)dr["p55"] == "0")

Comment: cant upvote yet sorry.

Comment: i have upvoted your post